# Слово лыжи. Вопрос о числе

Tags: морфология

В грамматическом словаре Зализняка написано, что слово *лыжи* используется только во множественном числе (pluralia tantum). Но ведь у этого слова есть ед. число. *У меня сломалась лыжа*. В словаре Ожегова написано:*ЛЫЖИ, лыж, ед. лыжа, -и, ж.*. Возникает вопрос: у слова *лыжи* есть единственное и множественное число или только множественное?

Comment: _Стася: В грамматичсеком словаре Зализняка написано, что слово лыжи используются **только** во множественном числе_… === Нет, не так. Зализняк приводит и  форму ед. ч.:   _"**лыжа** ж 4а"_.

Comment: slava1947, спасибо! Нашла.

Comment: Это другое значение. См. здесь. https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BB%D1%8B%D0%B6%D0%B8 Во втором значении ед. ч. нет

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы неправильно интерпретируете написанное у Зализняка.

Там речь идет **о лыжах как виде спорта или передвижения**. В этом значении (= бег, ходьба на лыжах) единственного числа нет или оно не используется в реальном контексте. Сравните -  *горные лыжи, охотничьи лыжи*.

Что касается самого приспособления, то у него, естественно, есть единственное число, и оно приводится в своем словарном гнезде.  Более того, у Зализняка в соответствии с применяемым им принципами построения словаря, именно оно считается первичным, а множественное число в этом значении (лыжи как инвентарь) - производным от единственного "лыжа".

(+)
Поскольку возникли недоразумения.
Дополню ссылкой. Это не Зализняк, но Викисловарь, построенный на материале словаря Зализняка.
https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BB%D1%8B%D0%B6%D0%B8
Во втором значении единственного числа нет. В первом, естественно, есть.

У слов типа "ботинки" второго значения нет.

И ботинки и лыжи (в первом значении) у Зализняка даются в гнезде формы единственного числа. 
И упоминания об отсутствии единственного, естественно, тоже нет.
Поэтому говорить, что этот вопрос относится ко всем подобным словам некорректно.

Другие же словари - да, подобные слова приводят множественное число как основную форму. Но это не ответ на собственно вопрос, как я его понимаю.

Совсем строго ответ можно сформулировать так.
**Единственное число есть только у одного значения слова "лыжи". Второе же значение единственного числа не имеет, хотя это авторы словарей обычно специально не оговаривают (кроме Зализняка)**

Comment: Спасибо! Вроде бы разобралась. Да, путаница у меня возникла из-за многозначности слова.

Answer (score 2):

Этот вопрос касается **любых парных предметов**, в словаре они представлены таким образом: ЛЫЖИ, лыж; мн. (ед. лыжа, -и; ж.),  БОТИНКИ,  мн. (ед. ботинок, м.).

Их основной (начальной) формой является форма мн. числа, но форму ед. числа они также имеют.

Comment: У Зализняка  не так. У него единственное число обычно первично даже в подобных случаях. И вообще дело не в парности, а в особом значении.

Comment: А если отвлечься от Зализняка, то для парных предметов какая форма является основной/начальной? Почему форма мн.числа в словаре стоит на первом месте, а форма ед. числа указана в скобках?

Comment: И ещё: если лыжи - это средство передвижения, вид спорта, то ботинки - это вид обуви.

Comment: Форма множественного  числа стоит на первом месте, потому что для парных предметов множественное число общеупотребимо! Вы покупаете лыжи, а не лыжу. Косте продадут перчатки, даже если у него нет второй руки. У Наташи промокли ноги, даже если фактически намочена одна нога. Вам неудобно слушать музыку, потому что не работают наушники, пусть даже один из них по-прежнему воспроизводит звук.

Comment: Вид обуви - это и есть единственное значение слова "ботинки". У ботинки нет, которое не имеет единственного числа. А "горные лыжи" такового не имеют точно. Короче, я не отрицаю, что парные предметы подобного типа действительно приводятся в большинстве словарей в гнездовой форме множественного числа, это так. Но у "лыж"  есть дополнительное значение, plural tantum,  которое Зализняка выделено в отдельную словарную статью. И это спутало автора вопроса. У ботинок и прочего такого значения нет точно.